# Configure MSBuild to launch PowerShell and run Import-Module $(TargetFileName)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I am learning how to develop PowerShell module in c# but there is no Visual Studio integration to launch PowerShell with the module imported.

I would like to configure MSBuild to launch PowerShell and run Import-Module $(TargetFileName).

I configured my project as a library project and set the debug options to launch PowerShell and set the command line argument to -NoExit -Command "Import-Module .\PowerShellModule.dll". However I am not satisfied with this solution.

My goal is to launch PowerShell with the module i'm working loaded and the debugger attached when I press F5 in Visual Studio. Ideally I would like to use the MSBuild Macro to create a reusable template and avoid using the csproj.user file.

Here is the relevent csproj.user file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartArguments>-NoExit -Command "Import-Module .\PowerShellModule.dll "</StartArguments>
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</StartProgram>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</StartProgram>
    <StartArguments>
    </StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by adding the following lines under PropertyGroup in my csproj.

```
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</StartProgram>
<StartArguments>-NoExit -Command "Import-Module .\$(AssemblyName).dll"</StartArguments>
```